# Replace evaporator coils when replacing R22 condenser with a 410a unit?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

My outside unit has died after 10 years of loyal service and I have two quotes to replace the old unit with a new SEER 16 unit.  One quote is to replace just the condenser and the other quote from another HVAC co includes new evaporator coils.  The reasoning is that the pressure would double on the 10 year old coils and that it would likely to develop a leak in the near future.  The proposed new evaporator is the exact same model etc that is currently installed.  If I want to go beyond SEER 16 I would have to replace the furnace unit as well.  What is the best approach?  The total difference between the two quotes is $2,200.
Condenser Model: Lennox 13ACD-048-230-01
Evaporator Model: CH33-48C-2F
Furnace Model: G40UH(X)

I also have the exact same setup on the 3-ton unit for upstairs so I am sure I will have to replace that soon enough as well.

Comment: If you're switching refrigerants, you're best off swapping out all the components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they said makes sense, but why the whole furnace and not just to evap coils?  They are tough to get at for sure, and the labor cost may be prohibitive to just replace the evap.  The other reason might be to pick up a rebate on the furnace if it's old enought.

Answer (score 0):

I agree replacing everything will save in the long run. Flushing the system rarely gets everything and residue in the system can shorten the new system life. When the company recoveres the R22 out of the system being removed from service that same R22 can be used to top your other R22 system legally. Other than that it is supposed to be sent back to a recycler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing the A/C system with 410A refrigerant then you will have to replace the indoor coil and refrigeration lines as well due to the suction lines on the 410A units are larger. They still make HCFC22 refrigerant units that would allow you to replace only the outdoor condensing unit.